# What is the cause of this error when deploying Dash app to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I am trying to deploy a dash app to heroku and am getting an error with heroku when actually trying to run 'heroku open'.  Here is the end of the log:

```
2021-01-12T01:49:45.730762+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-01-12T01:49:45.951284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-12T01:49:46.050829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-01-12T02:06:59.854689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rxmoney.herokuapp.com request_id=bf61c1ac-30b6-42e5-89d7-9e4c80f6a0c3 fwd="74.90.2.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-12T02:07:00.407100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rxmoney.herokuapp.com request_id=7ba5f530-0f04-4c95-b5d4-32c90dd23555 fwd="74.90.2.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-12T02:41:50.993320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rxmoney.herokuapp.com request_id=8556b46e-0407-47c5-b3cb-ab4e7f056301 fwd="74.90.2.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-12T02:41:51.505388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rxmoney.herokuapp.com request_id=ffec240b-9f20-49fd-9821-73af2e438962 fwd="74.90.2.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here are my requirements:

```
Click==7.0
dash==1.7.0
dash-core-components==1.6.0
dash-html-components==1.0.2
dash-renderer==1.2.2
dash-table==4.5.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pandas
plotly==4.4.1
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.13.0
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing here...